# VBA to AutoSUM selected Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on automating some reports by pasting data from raw files into my Template called PA Reach. I have named a range "Sumrow" and I need VBA to autosum the numbers above in each of the loops after pasting the data in. Here is what I have and I'm getting errors:

```
Workbooks.Open datapath & datafile1 & OutputFileExt
  Sheets("Rep").Activate
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter        

  For i = 1 To terrs_to_generate
    Workbooks(builder).Sheets("Control").Activate

    Range("Reportnum") = i
    currfile = Range("CurrFile").Value
    currterr = Range("CurrTerr").Value
    currRep = Range("currRep").Value
    terrname = Range("terrname").Value
    DMName = Range("DMName").Value
    TMStartDate = Range("TMstartdate").Value

    'open template
    Workbooks.Open templatepath & templatefile & OutputFileExt

    Set currtemplatefile = ActiveWorkbook

    Sheets("Control").Select
    Sheets("control").Range("terrname") = terrname
    Sheets("control").Range("repname") = currRep
    Sheets("control").Range("reportdate") = reportdate
    Sheets("control").Range("TMstartdate") = TMStartDate
    Sheets("control").Range("DMName") = DMName
    Sheets("control").Range("Territory") = currterr

    Workbooks(datafile1 & OutputFileExt).Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=currterr

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown), Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
    currtemplatefile.Activate
    Sheets("PA Reach").Select
    Range("pasterange").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    currtemplatefile.Activate
    Range("formatrow").Copy

    Range("pasterange").Select
    Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 0)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    'Delete PasteRange
    Range("pasterange").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    'Value Range Sheet so no formulas show
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   Range("A1").Select



 Sheets("control").Delete
'need to add in sum total
Range("sumrow1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = "=Sum(" & Range("sumrow1").Address(True, True) & ")"



    'save as and close
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(reportpath & currfile & OutputFileExt)   'not working
```

Comment: You could clean that code up a lot following [Avoid Select/Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `Select` `Range("sumrow")`, and then use `Selection`, you can modify the `Formula` to the `Range` directly.

Try the code below, it will put the `Sum` formula at the row below the bottom row of your "sumrow" named range:

```
Range("sumrow").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = "=Sum(" & Range("sumrow").Address(True, True) & ")"
```

Comment: This is awesome, and it worked. However, it is SUMming sideways, how can I make it sum just the row above?

Comment: @SQUISH what do you mean just the row above ? you want to sum only the last row from the entire range ?

Comment: I want to sum the cells in the sumrow directly above, right now it's summing the whole row..does that make sense?

Comment: @SQUISH you want to sum all cells in the row above ? like if I'm at Cell E3, you want to sum cells(D2:D5) ?

Comment: what you said above is correct, sorry, I do want the sum formula at the row below the bottom row of my sumrow named range...i'll re edit my code, it's not working.

Comment: something is not working the xlDown, when i put the error over the code xlDown (=-4121)...

Comment: Range("sumrow").Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=Sum(" & Range("sumrow").Address & ")"  this works but it selects my entire sumrow row, and I only want it to sum the totals direct above each cell below it, sumrow consists of 4 columns of numbers...

Comment: @SQUISH your description doesn't make much sense to me - it would be really helpful if you could amend your question with a sample of the data.

Comment: @SQUISH please edit your post and add a screen-shot of your excel sheet, describe where is `Range("sumrow")` defined, which data you want to Sum